# Counting Vowels using a For Loop

Tags: visual-c++, c++11

Hey guys I haven't been able to find the proper guidance on this specific Vowel counting program so any help would be appreciated.

This is my code so far, I'm not entirely sure where the error lies (probably in the for loop since I'm pretty green with them).  The vowelCount variable is not counting properly either.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    char letter(10);
    int vowelCount(0);
    cout << "Enter a maximum of 10 characters: ";
    cin >> letter;

    for (int i = 0; i <= letter; i++) {
        if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'A' ||
          letter == 'e' || letter == 'E' ||
          letter == 'i' || letter == 'I' ||
          letter == 'o' || letter == 'O' ||
          letter == 'u' || letter == 'U') {
            vowelCount++;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nTotal number of vowels: " << vowelCount;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The C++ standard library have many nice [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), for example ones that does [counting](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).

Comment: `char letter(10)` is a single char with the value of 10, you probably want `char letter[10]`

Comment: @LukeB. The array you demonstrated works but is of out of the scope of how I wanted this program to run unfortunately.  Arrays and strings are covered in the next chapter while this exercise is in the preceding chapter.  So are there any alternatives to the variable changes sans use of arrays?

Comment: Then you have to read a single letter at a time *in the loop*.

Comment: @user3465469 I edited the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton both of you!  I can't believe it didn't dawn on me earlier to put the cin command within the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few mistakes with your code:

`char letter(10)` is not an array of char, but a single char.
Your `for` loop goes to the letter value (which is 10, granted) but will not be once you fix `letter` to be an array.
Also, when you read the variable letter, you should use the `operator[]` to access its elements.

The following is the correct code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    char letter;
    int vowelCount(0);

    cout << "Enter a maximum of 10 characters: ";

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cin >> letter;
    if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'A' ||
        letter == 'e' || letter == 'E' ||
        letter == 'i' || letter == 'I' ||
        letter == 'o' || letter == 'O' ||
        letter == 'u' || letter == 'U')
    {
        vowelCount++;
    }
}
cout << "\nTotal number of vowels: " << vowelCount;
cout << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you declare a single character (and initialize to `10`), that you read into. Then you loop from zero to the ASCII value of that letter. You should either read into a [string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) or an *array* of characters.

If you go for the latter (array of characters) remember that in C++ such strings need one extra character (to terminate the string). So if you want a string of 10 characters, you have to declare the array to be 11 characters big.